# Function that converts GPS coordinates to ENU coordinates?

Tags: java, gps

I want to convert gps coordinates (latitude,longitude) to ENU (est,north,up) coordinates.

I Know theory about this problem, but I have little time to implement it so i ask if exists java code to do it!

Thanks

Comment: ENU coordinates need a reference point. Do you have any?

Comment: Why so many downvotes? This is not bad question...

Comment: Wikipedia shows an algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_north_up#ECEF_to.2Ffrom_ENU_coordinates

Comment: @Kamil it is badly formulated. Also, asking for a specific implementation sounds like a help vampirism - it's better to ask for an algorithm

Comment: oh yeah, maybe it can be badly formulated, but I don't want a correction of my code. I want to know if exists some tool, java code etc to do it! I know theory but i have little time to implement it!

Comment: When you finally write such function please publish it, community will be graceful :)

Comment: I put two solutions. I used the latter!

Answer (score 6):

In [this](https://catalogue.nla.gov.au/Record/2027305) publication there is a lot of information on topic. Additionally there is a Matlab code - this is a good place to start from.

The relevant part (from "Converting GPS Coordinates (Φλh) to Navigation Coordinates (ENU)" by S. P. Drake):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple implementation in Java to convert GPS coordinates to ENU coordinates.

```
public List<Double> convertGpsToECEF(double lat, double longi, float alt) {

    double a=6378.1;
    double b=6356.8;
    double N;
    double e= 1-(Math.pow(b, 2)/Math.pow(a, 2));
    N= a/(Math.sqrt(1.0-(e*Math.pow(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat)), 2))));
    double cosLatRad=Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat));
    double cosLongiRad=Math.cos(Math.toRadians(longi));
    double sinLatRad=Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat));
    double sinLongiRad=Math.sin(Math.toRadians(longi));
    double x =(N+0.001*alt)*cosLatRad*cosLongiRad;
    double y =(N+0.001*alt)*cosLatRad*sinLongiRad;
    double z =((Math.pow(b, 2)/Math.pow(a, 2))*N+0.001*alt)*sinLatRad;

    List<Double> ecef= new ArrayList<>();
    ecef.add(x);
    ecef.add(y);
    ecef.add(z);

    return ecef;


}


public List<Double> convertECEFtoENU(List<Double> ecefUser, List<Double> ecefPOI, double lat, double longi){

    double cosLatRad=Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat));
    double cosLongiRad=Math.cos(Math.toRadians(longi));
    double sinLatRad=Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat));
    double sinLongiRad=Math.sin(Math.toRadians(longi));


    List<Double> vector = new ArrayList<>();

    vector.add(ecefUser.get(0)-ecefPOI.get(0));
    vector.add(ecefUser.get(1)-ecefPOI.get(1));
    vector.add(ecefUser.get(2)-ecefPOI.get(2));

    double e= vector.get(0)*(-sinLongiRad)+vector.get(0)*(cosLongiRad);
    double n= vector.get(0)*(-sinLatRad)*(cosLongiRad)+vector.get(1)*(-sinLatRad)*(sinLongiRad)+vector.get(2)*cosLatRad;
    double u= vector.get(0)*(cosLatRad)*(cosLongiRad)+vector.get(1)*(cosLatRad)*(sinLongiRad)+vector.get(2)*sinLatRad;


    List<Double> enu= new ArrayList<>();
    enu.add(e);
    enu.add(n);
    enu.add(u);

    return enu;
    }
```

Comment: I think there's an error in convertECEFtoENU.   East should be calculated as: 
```double e= vector.get(0)*(-sinLongiRad)+vector.get(1)*(cosLongiRad);```  
Note ```vector.get(1)```

Answer (score 0):

The formulas you find at wiki

[From ECEF To ENU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_datum#Local_east.2C_north.2C_up_.28ENU.29_coordinates)

In the lack of a formula editor, the answer cannot posted here.

Comment: I've said it elsewhere, and I'll say it here: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers are not welcome on stack overflow.

Comment: @JanDvorak it would be preferable but in lack of a formula editor it does not make sense. a link only answer is better than no answer, feel free to give your own answer, whithout copyright violations.

Comment: What about migration to some other site that does support formulas? Reformulated appropriately, this could well suit [Math.se]

Comment: This answer isn't targeting the original question: LLA -> ENU!
Thankfully, alex's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simple method. It's uses the idea that it may be a good enough approximation to consider the earth as "flat"

http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#flat

[image: method]

Answer (score 0):

Using the [goGPS library](http://www.gogps-project.org/), [Coordinates.java](https://github.com/goGPS-Project/goGPS_Java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/gogpsproject/Coordinates.java)

```
 /**
 * @param origin
 * @return Local (ENU) coordinates
 */
public void computeLocal(Coordinates target) {
    if(this.geod==null) computeGeodetic();

    SimpleMatrix R = rotationMatrix(this);

    enu = R.mult(target.minusXYZ(this));

}
```

See also [TopocentricCoordinates.java](https://github.com/goGPS-Project/goGPS_Java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/gogpsproject/TopocentricCoordinates.java)

```
    public void computeTopocentric(Coordinates origin, Coordinates target) {

    origin.computeLocal(target);

    double E = origin.getE();//enu.get(0);
    double N = origin.getN();//enu.get(1);
    double U = origin.getU();//enu.get(2);
```

Answer (score -2):

Other Solution is:

```
public static double[] fatCoordinates(double lat,double lon){
    double phi = Math.toRadians(lat);
    double lambda = Math.toRadians(lon);
    double e2 = Math.pow(WGS_E,2);
    double Rn = WGS_A / Math.sqrt(1 - e2 * Math.pow(Math.sin(phi), 2));
    double[] XYZ = new double[3];
    XYZ[0] = Rn * Math.cos(phi) * Math.cos(lambda);
    XYZ[1] = Rn * Math.cos(phi) * Math.sin(lambda);
    XYZ[2] = Rn * (1 - e2) * Math.sin(phi);

    return XYZ;


}
```

with

```
public static final double WGS_A = 6378137.0;


public static final double WGS_E = 0.0818191908426;
```

It's taken from https://josm.openstreetmap.de/browser/josm/trunk/src/org/openstreetmap/josm/data/projection/Ellipsoid.java?rev=4382

Comment: where is the reference latitdue, longitude for ENU?

Comment: if you see the link, you'll see that reference latitude and longitude isn't there because this isn't really ENU system, but it's a simplification. however, this method allows you to consider earth "flat".

Comment: for earth flat there are many solutions, much simpler than ENU, but you have asked for ENU, not for transforming lat,lon to cartesian coordinates

Comment: yes, I know. Iput this solution to give an alternative. Probably, i must to say it but i think it's clear that it's not a solution for ENU.